# Numerics with Scipy: functions call and compiling

Tags: python, scipy, numeric, numerical-integration

I'm new in numerics with Scipy. In particular I would like to integrate a system of (complex) differential equations. I notice that `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` can do the job. Since my equations depend on some numerical parameter I wrote a builder class in order to build the equations as well as the initial conditions

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

class eq_builder:
    def __init__(self, parameters):
        self._parameters = parameters

    def build_eqs():
        def numerical_function(t, y):
            #here y is a list. This numerical function uses parameters and return a list
        return numerical_function

    def build_ics():
        #generate and returns initial conditions (as a list)
```

then I use

```
a = eq_builder(my_parameter)
solve_ivp(a.build_eqs(), [0, 10000], a.build_ics())
```

### QUESTIONS

1. Since the `numerical_function` will be called several times by the `solve_ivp` is there a way to *compile* it to make the process of computation faster?
2. In the definition of `numerical_function` should I limit as I can some more abstract (but espressive) things such as `map` over a list or list comprehension?
3. Do you have any other advice to give me? Consider that the number of equation in the aforesaid system is of the order of several hundreds.

Answer (score 1):

> Since the numerical_function will be called several times by the solve_ivp is there a way to compile it to make the process of computation faster?

You'd have to go out of your way to do so. Taking a step back, your assumption seems to be that "compiled" code is always faster than interpreted Python. That is not the case.
It is true that simple things like loops etc are slower in Python than in, e.g., C, but that's is the reason you just don't write large loops in Python. You rather use numpy arrays with their intrinsic functions. For example `numpy.dot(a, b)` is *much* faster than anything you'll write yourself in C because `numpy.dot` uses some fancy libraries (BLAS, in that case) that do the job better than you ever could.

> In the definition of numerical_function should I limit as I can some more abstract (but espressive) things such as map over a list or list comprehension?

That's a matter of taste.

> Do you have any other advice to give me? Consider that the number of equation in the aforesaid system is of the order of several hundreds.

First get it working, even if terribly slow, then try to find out *where* your code is slow, and try to improve there.